# How to create a ScrollView that can adapt to its children's changing size

Tags: ios, swiftui

[Beta 4] I have a list of cards, each of which can be expanded when the user taps on them to display more information.

However, the containing ScrollView does not expand or contract when the size of the cards changes.

The only way I have found to make this work is to use List — which seems to adjust automatically to the content, but this is not what I want as it introduces other features of the list (most notably the dividers).

Not using a ForEach (i.e. just stacking several `Card()` yields the same result.

In Beta 3 I found a workaround by making `expanded` a `@Binding`, and then have an array of `@State` for each card, but since Beta 4, this doesn't work anymore as the changing value does not propagate up anymore unless I also have an element in the parent view that binds to this array directly (i.e. also a toggle). It seems that the state of @State only changes now if there are actually elements directly bound to it.

```
struct ExpandableChildViewTest: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(1...10) { _ in
                    Card()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
            .border(Color.green, width: 1)
    }
}

struct Card: View {

    @State private var expanded = true

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: expanded ? 350: 100)
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .padding(.vertical)
                .tapAction() {
                    self.expanded.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect (hope) the containing Scrollview to adjust its size when its children change size, but that doesn't happen. This leads to either content falling out of the Scrollview, or a lot of extra space inside the Scrollview.

[The picture shows the extra white space at the top because the second card is collapsed. The outer Scrollview does not recompute itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWqV2.png)

Answer (score 0):

(my reputation does not yet allow to comment, so I'm using this way...) 
I have a similar situation: a timeline with different granulations (decade, year, month etc.), and the user shall be able to zoom smoothly, while the scale adopts itself accordingly. The only way I found up to now is to calculate the overall width of the scale for the current magnification, and to hand it over to the view through the model. The embedded view then gets a `.frame` with that width, and the `ScrollView` then handles the scrolling correctly.

However, this is far away from being elegant. Because the embedded view actually knows its width, it should be possible somehow (but how?) to make the `ScrollView` aware of that width. In my environment, the ScrollView (without the explicit `.frame`) just shows an empty screen, with the explicit `.frame` everything's fine (but not performant enough).

Btw: Since Beta 5, there are changes to the way how binding is performed. You now set the model in the view with `@ObservedObject var model: Model`, and you propagate the model's changes using `@Published var something: SomeType`, this is much easier than before.